# Using Google's TextToSpeech API on Heroku

Tags: heroku, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to use [Google's TextToSpeech REST API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/text/synthesize#request-body) on heroku.

I have a service account keyfile, which works fine locally, but I cannot figure out how I could make it work on Heroku, where the Google Cloud SDK is not installed.  That is, consider this [sample curl call from the quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart):

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{
  'input':{
    'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
  },
  'voice':{
    'languageCode':'en-gb',
    'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
    'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
  },
  'audioConfig':{
    'audioEncoding':'MP3'
  }
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-output.txt
```

which depends on the bash command `$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`, which in turn depends on the google cloud SDK being installed (I have the mac version installed locally).

I looked into using the [ruby client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.53.0/google/cloud), which I believe handles the authentication under the hood if it has the keyfile via the `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON` env variable, but it does not appear to support TextToSpeech.

How can I make TextToSpeech API calls on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need to use the service account credentials to get an access token via OAuth 2.0. You can do this manually or use an SDK. Google as a set of Speech-to-Text Client Libraries at the link here. There are a few languages supported including Ruby, as well as C#, Go, Java, Node.js, PHP and Python:

- https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go

You can install the Ruby SDK with the following:

```
$ gem install google-cloud-speech
```

Then add the filepath to your credentials files as an environment variable:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to[FILE_NAME].json"
```

I use Go and have a Google Text-to-Speech example here calling both `text.synthesize` (like your example) and `voices.list`. This example stores the Google key file contents in an environment variable which makes it easy to read from a Heroku instance. While this uses the [`google/google-api-go-client` SDK](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/texttospeech/v1beta1/texttospeech-gen.go), I just noticed and will consider upgrading to [`GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go) now.

- https://github.com/grokify/googleutil/blob/master/texttospeech/v1beta1/examples/quickstart/main.go

This retrieves an access token and then instantiates the Google Go Client SDK:

- https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client

The Google Go SDK supports Text-to-Speech here:

- https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/tree/master/texttospeech/v1beta1

Go is easy to get on to Heroku as well using `godep` as documented here:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/go-support

I also have a scaffolding app that will create the files you need to enable the "Deploy to Heroku" button for a Go app here:

- https://github.com/grokify/goheroku

If you use Go and have any questions let me know.